# CS50 pset4 Blur

Tags: c, cs50

I do not understand why my code does not work. It returns a very strange image, with VERY dark colors. I read someone else's code on a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203062/19299155), and to me it looks like a very similar concept and approach. If someone could explain to me why mine doesn't work I'd be very grateful.
One thing I do not understand about the other guy's code is why he updates the pixel value when he does (//assigning new pixel values) because it would mean that the average of other pixels would be using the new value of the now updated pixel instad of the original. (I hope I am explaining myself correctly).
I also read this post ([cs50 - pset4 - blur](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64941308/19299155)) this guy seems to have the same problem as me, and very similar code but the answers people gave him don't seem to apply to me.
Here is my code:
helpers.c

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE blurred[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i<height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<width; j++){
            float colorCount = 0.0;
            blurred[i][j].rgbtBlue = 0;
            blurred[i][j].rgbtGreen = 0;
            blurred[i][j].rgbtRed = 0;

            for (int count = -1; count<2; count++){
                if (((count+i) >= 0) && ((count+i) < height)){
                    for (int count2 = -1; count2<2; count2++){
                        if (((count2+j) >= 0) && ((count2+j) < width)){
                            blurred[i][j].rgbtBlue += image[i+count][j+count2].rgbtBlue;
                            blurred[i][j].rgbtGreen += image[i+count][j+count2].rgbtGreen;
                            blurred[i][j].rgbtRed += image[i+count][j+count2].rgbtRed;
                            colorCount += 1.0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            blurred[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blurred[i][j].rgbtBlue/colorCount);
            blurred[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(blurred[i][j].rgbtGreen/colorCount);
            blurred[i][j].rgbtRed = round(blurred[i][j].rgbtRed/colorCount);

        }
    }

for (int i = 0; i<height; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<width; j++){
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blurred[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = blurred[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = blurred[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried 2 nested for loops starting at -1 so it would go through the 3x3 adjacent pixels as -1 0 +1. for count = -1 it would go count2 =-1 then count2=0 then count2 = 1. then count = 0 and count2 =-1 then count2=0 then count2 = 1. and so on.

This is helpers.h

```
// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);
```

This is bmp.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Common Data Types
 *
 * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++
 * primitive data types.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
 */
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

/**
 * BITMAPFILEHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
 * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(VS.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    WORD   bfType;
    DWORD  bfSize;
    WORD   bfReserved1;
    WORD   bfReserved2;
    DWORD  bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPFILEHEADER;

/**
 * BITMAPINFOHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure contains information about the
 * dimensions and color format of a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(VS.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    DWORD  biSize;
    LONG   biWidth;
    LONG   biHeight;
    WORD   biPlanes;
    WORD   biBitCount;
    DWORD  biCompression;
    DWORD  biSizeImage;
    LONG   biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG   biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD  biClrUsed;
    DWORD  biClrImportant;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER;

/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

This is filter.c

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Define allowable filters
    char *filters = "begr";

    // Get filter flag and check validity
    char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
    if (filter == '?')
    {
        printf("Invalid filter.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure only one filter
    if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
    {
        printf("Only one filter allowed.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != optind + 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];

    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 4;
    }

    // Open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 5;
    }

    // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 6;
    }

    // Get image's dimensions
    int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
    int width = bi.biWidth;

    // Allocate memory for image
    RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store image.\n");
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        return 7;
    }

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Read row into pixel array
        fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

        // Skip over padding
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    // Filter image
    switch (filter)
    {
        // Blur
        case 'b':
            blur(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Edges
        case 'e':
            edges(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Grayscale
        case 'g':
            grayscale(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Reflect
        case 'r':
            reflect(height, width, image);
            break;
    }

    // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write new pixels to outfile
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Write row to outfile
        fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, outptr);

        // Write padding at end of row
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // Free memory for image
    free(image);

    // Close files
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    return 0;
}```

This is Makefile
```filter:
    clang -ggdb3 -gdwarf-4 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow -lm -o filter filter.c helpers.c
````

To reproduce use any .bmp image. when you run the program, the command line arguments are -e INFILE.bmp OUTFILE.bmp

Comment: What exactly is the type definition of `RGBTRIPLE`? If this is a typical pixel format with 8 bits per pixel, there's simply not enough bits to use that as an accumulator for your blur kernel. The values will overflow. If they are some other data type (_e.g._ `float`) then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: SO requires that you provide a [mre] when asking for debugging help. That MRE should be able to be copied and pasted into a code editor, compiled, and executed to reproduce the problem. You've not provided that code. For more information, see [ask] and the [help].

Comment: @KenWhite I understand. Its my first time posting, but ill be sure to do that next time.

Comment: Instead of only applying that knowledge to the future you can [edit] this question and make it useful and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for the definition of `RGBTRIPLE` online (since you did not provide it) yields [this post](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/20125/how-does-rgbtriple-triple-know-whitch-pixel-to-store) where the definition is:

```
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

This poses an issue for your current blur kernel calculation, because you are using a `RGBTRIPLE` value to accumulate the sum of all pixels in the 3x3 kernel. Each color channel in the pixel uses the entire range, and so the moment you add data from another pixel to this, you risk exceeding the maximum possible value that can be stored. This will discard the carry bit from such an operation and wrap the result to remain in the 0-255 range.

The reason your output is "dark" is precisely because for most of your image the maximum possible value for a channel is `round(255.0 / 9)`, which is 28. On the edges of your image, that will be brighter, but still never better than `round(255.0 / 4)`, which is 64. Within this narrow range, you're also likely to see jagged artifacts or banding where the color channels wrapped after discarding overflow bits.

Even the answers you linked to point out the same thing, which you mistakenly assert *"don't seem to apply to me"*. That is incorrect. There is absolutely no way that this isn't a problem for you. Allow me to fix your code, and maybe just rename some variables along the way to improve readability:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int count = 0;
        float sumRed = 0.0f, sumGreen= 0.0f, sumBlue = 0.0f;
        
        for (int dy = -1; dy <= 1; dy++) {
            int ky = y + dy;
            if (ky >= 0 && ky < height) {
                for (int dx = -1; dx <= 1; dx++) {
                    int kx = x + dx;
                    if (kx >= 0 && kx < width) {
                        sumBlue  += (float)image[ky][kx].rgbtBlue;
                        sumGreen += (float)image[ky][kx].rgbtGreen;
                        sumRed   += (float)image[ky][kx].rgbtRed;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        blurred[y][x].rgbtBlue  = round(sumBlue / count);
        blurred[y][x].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / count);
        blurred[y][x].rgbtRed   = round(sumRed / count);
    }
}

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        image[y][x] = blurred[y][x];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry I did not include the rgbtriple struct code. I'll be sure to provide everything on any other post. I'm rereading the posts I linked to, but I still don't find an answer like the one you provided.
Again, thanks for your answer, have a good day.